# How to roll back touchpad driver to synaptic?

Tags: drivers, unity, gnome, touchpad, synaptics

I wanted to try gnome3, I followed omg ubuntu's guide which was basically adding the PPA 
Everything was working great except it wasn't, I was getting low on root under 600 MB, so I had to uninstall gnome3 first I tried
`sudo apt-get install gnome3 gnome-shell` as that what I installed in the first place, now unity was broken and I login to black screen and the grey sub menus disappeared, I figured that I should use `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove the `gnome3-*` still no use.
I tried to reinstall lightdm and this didn't fix anything
finally I found this answer that said I should use ppapurge I used and unity was back wokring. ouldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

Now to the current question touchpad tap to click wasn't working, some answers on askubuntu advised to use `synclient` it kept replying with this `Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?` I found that gnome3 uses `libinput` drivers instead of `syntapics` I succeded in enabling the touchpad using `xinput`. So how do I revert the touchpad drivers to synaptics!? My touchpad is an Elantech touchpad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled the libinput package and synaptic took over
just write down in terminal

`sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput`